# How to insert a timestamp in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle DB with a `timestamp` field in it. What is the correct SQL code to insert a `timestamp` into this field?

Comment: "I can't find this info anywhere."  The Oracle documenation is comprehensive and online.  Find it here : http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/toc.htm

Answer (score 166, accepted):

```
insert
into tablename (timestamp_value)
values (TO_TIMESTAMP(:ts_val, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
```

if you want the current time stamp to be inserted then:

```
insert
into tablename (timestamp_value)
values (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Comment: Why `TO_DATE` instead of `TO_TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: It doesn't matter for this simple `INSERT` statement, but in general you do not want to use bind variables like this.  The type conversion in your first statement prevents it from being bind sensitive, which limits Oracle's ability to create good plans.  The optimizer may work better if you use `values (:ts_val)` instead, assuming :ts_val maps directly to a timestamp.

Comment: @JonHeller Can you show a specific example of how using `to_timestamp` would cause a bad execution plan for a plan-able SQL statement? I can show an example of how it would not. Instead, what I think we all want to avoid is *unexpected* data type coercion that precludes using an expected row source operation (i.e., the optimal one).

Comment: @jeff6times7 See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/jonheller1/5764de7185b28a54fbf854140975c881) for an explanation of how unconverted bind variables can outperform converted bind variables.  The difference probably only matters if the data is skewed.  With native bind types, Oracle can understand the data better and make better estimates based on the values.

Answer (score 36):

```
INSERT
INTO    mytable (timestamp_field)
VALUES  (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `SYSTIMESTAMP` are Oracle reserved words for this purpose. They are the timestamp analog of `SYSDATE`.

Answer (score 27):

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (TIMESTAMP_VALUE) VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('2014-07-02 06:14:00.742000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'));
```

Answer (score 11):

Kind of depends on where the value you want to insert is coming from.  If you want to insert the current time you can use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as shown in other answers (or `SYSTIMESTAMP`).

If you have a time as a string and want to convert it to a timestamp, use an expression like

```
to_timestamp(:timestamp_as_string,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3')
```

The time format components are, I hope, self-explanatory, except that `FF3` means 3 digits of sub-second precision.  You can go as high as 6 digits of precision.

If you are inserting from an application, the best answer may depend on how the date/time value is stored in your language.  For instance you can map certain Java objects directly to a `TIMESTAMP` column, but you need to understand the `JDBC` type mappings.

Answer (score 8):

I prefer ANSI timestamp literals:

```
insert into the_table 
  (the_timestamp_column)
values 
  (timestamp '2017-10-12 21:22:23');
```

More details in the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062

Comment: Oracle 11. Field defined as TIMESTAMP(6) not NULL.  Using  ```timestamp '2019-05-16 10:05:51:19:277401'``` I have this error: ORA-01882: timezone region not found

Answer (score 2):

One can simply use

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(MY_TIMESTAMP_FIELD)
VALUES (TIMESTAMP '2019-02-15 13:22:11.871+02:00');
```

This way you won't have to worry about date format string, just use default timestamp format.

Works with Oracle 11, have no idea if it does for earlier Oracle versions.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting date in sql

```
insert
into tablename (timestamp_value)
values ('dd-mm-yyyy hh-mm-ss AM');
```

If suppose we wanted to insert system date

```
insert
into tablename (timestamp_value)
values (sysdate);
```

Answer (score 1):

For my own future reference:

With cx_Oracle use cursor.setinputsize(...):

```
mycursor = connection.cursor();

mycursor.setinputsize( mytimestamp=cx_Oracle.TIMESTAMP );
params = { 'mytimestamp': timestampVar };
cusrsor.execute("INSERT INTO mytable (timestamp_field9 VALUES(:mytimestamp)", params);
```

No converting in the db needed. See [Oracle Documentation](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/prez-python-timesanddates-093014.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to make the field Nullable, then after that so simple - instead of putting a value put this code `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 0):

The below sample working fine for me.

```
INSERT INTO "DB"."TBL" (UPDATEDDATETIME) 
VALUES (TO_TIMESTAMP('2022-07-12 17:16:05.551000000', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF'))
```

Answer (score -8):

```
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
id int identity(1, 1) NOT NULL,
Somecolmn varchar (5),
LastChanged [timestamp] NOT NULL)
```

this works for mssql 2012

```
INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES('hello',DEFAULT)
```