# SQL - Inserting a time value into column?

Tags: sql, time, timestamp

I am using Oracle SQL and I would like to insert a time value (eg 15:45 or 15:45:00) into a column which has a data type of TIMESTAMP. I have tried the following but It gives a error about it not being a valid month.

```
INSERT trainTbl(Dest, trainTime)
VALUES
('Waterloo', '15:00:00');
```

Would appreciate if someone could put me on the right direction. 
Thanks

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420833/insert-timestamp-oracle)

Comment: not a duplicate, I tried that before I posted this and I get a Date before the time which I dont want. I just want the time.

Comment: please, copy/past the full message error you got

Comment: Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: I dont want the date in this column, just the time. I already have the date in a seperate column.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle's `TIMESTAMP` data type holds a complete time and date. You cannot use it to store a time only; either store a complete time and date, or use a different data type for your column.

Some options for ways to store the time only are discussed in [How to store only time; not date and time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1786418/2359271). However, if you're already storing the date in another column, you should probably just store this information together. There is a reason Oracle provides the data types that it does.