# SQL ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis error

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to create a table using TIME() datatype for a column with the following statement(ok, i shortened it a bit, i only want to figure out how to maka a column with TIME values, not TIMESTAMP)

```
CREATE TABLE Random
( 
   sosire TIME(), 
   nume VARCHAR(20)
);
```

Can you please help me a bit? Thanks

Comment: there is no `TIME` datatype in Oracle. What is wrong with `TIMESTAMP`?

Comment: it complicates the project that i have to do...but regarding this, how do i create a correct TIMESTAMP insert into statement? tried several times but didn't succeed

Comment: I guess you should post your attempts here and possible error messages as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420833/how-to-insert-a-timestamp-in-oracle

Comment: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=55848c0948ea92b64805ed35a7883fc4

Comment: sorry for the previous post, i copied the exact lines and i got this: ORA-00911: invalid character

Comment: Instead of time, perhaps you can use number of seconds.

Comment: but why do i get that invalid character error now? it seems alright to me

Comment: No it's not "alright". There is no `time` data type in Oracle

Answer (score 0):

You can extract time units from a timestamp column, and you can also set the default value (at insert) to current value of systimestamp. e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Random
( 
   sosire timestamp default systimestamp, 
   nume VARCHAR(20)
);
```